# Is there any way to disable the film grain effect?

Tags: outlast

I understand that it's probably just there for the sake of making an atmosphere, but it just makes thing look bad in my opinion. I don't see any options to disable it from the games main menu.

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 7):

Go to `~\Steam\SteamApps\common\Outlast\Engine\Config`

Open up the `ConsoleVariables.ini` and find this string:

`ImageGrain = 0.0`

Just set the values as listed here for no film grain.

That should fix your problem, albeit I haven't tested it out.

([Source](http://danielmeier.wordpress.com/2013/09/05/outlast-how-to-tweak-fov-fps-texture-resolution-motion-blur-and-more/))